# What is the inverse function of $x-\log(\log(x))$?

Tags: functions, inverse

What is the inverse function of $f(x)=x-\log(\log(x))$? If we restrict the domain to e.g. $x\in[2,+\infty[$, the function should have an inverse, but I am unable to compute it.

Comment: If this is part of a bigger problem, perhaps you don't need to find the inverse to solve it, maybe its existence suffices.

Comment: So, you are trying to solve $y=x-\log\log x$ for $x$. There is no expression for the solution in terms of elementary functions, nor even for $y=x-\log x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I speculate that there might be a way to express it in terms of the (non-elementary) [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), but I'm not familiar enough with the function to say for sure...

Comment: @GerryMyerson That explains why all my effort was unsuccessful. A "meta question": Should I delete my question? Or do you want to post your comment as an answer? Or do we just leave it without an answer?

Comment: I think the best solution is for someone to find a reference where my statement is backed up by a proof, and then post a link as an answer. Maybe the question has been asked before on this website, and it's just a matter of finding it and linking it here. But please don't delete.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Pretty good approximation with $x + \log \log x.$ There may be corrections in the line of an asymptotic expansion after that.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with the W-function...although we can do $x-\log(x)$! If you really want something to work with try a series inversion. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem.  Mathematica can do it for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

We get a very good approximation with
$$ g(x) = x + \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x \log x} \right) \log \log x.  $$
Note $g(e) = f(e) = e.$
My calculator says 
$$ g(f(10)) \approx 10.00061672; \; \; f(g(10)) \approx 10.00062308 $$
$$ g(f(100)) \approx 100.0000241; \; \; f(g(10)) \approx 100.0000234 $$
$$ g(f(1000)) \approx 1000.000000; \; \; f(g(1000)) \approx 1000.000001 $$